# Latest Notification alerts

Tags: php, push-notification, moengage

I am using https://www.moengage.com/ to generate the smart trigger campaign notification alert for my users  for desktop and mobile.
using their `<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m,n){
i['moengage_object']=r;t={}; q = function(f){return function(){(i['moengage_q']=i['moengage_q']||[]).push({f:f,a:arguments});};};
f = ['track_event','add_user_attribute','add_first_name','add_last_name','add_email','add_mobile',
'add_user_name','add_gender','add_birthday','destroy_session','add_unique_user_id','moe_events','call_web_push','track','location_type_attribute'];
for(k in f){t[f[k]]=q(f[k]);}
a=s.createElement(o);m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m);
i['moe']=i['moe'] || function(){n=arguments[0];return t;}; a.onload=function(){if(n){i[r] = moe(n);}};
})(window,document,'script','https://cdn.moengage.com/webpush/moe_webSdk.min.latest.js','Moengage'); 

Moengage = moe({
  app_id:"MyAppID",
  debug_logs: 0
}); 
</script>
```

campaign is created and I can view the notification alert pop up but when I click "allow" it is not throwing the notifications.

how do I solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I work at MoEngage currently. Smart Triggers are not instantaneous. There is a processing time of about 5 minutes before the notification is sent out. What you can do instead is  wait for our callback event (docs -> https://docs.moengage.com/docs/tracking-opt-ins-on-your-own#section-this-is-how-you-can-add-listeners-for-the-events-mentioned-above-) and show a welcome notification by javascript.

```js
...
else if (e.detail == "opt_in_allowed") {
  spawnNotification();
}
...

function spawnNotification() {
  var title = "Your title";
  var body = "Your body";
  var icon = "https://path.to.your/icon/file";
  var options = {
    body: body,
    icon: icon
  };
  navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(sw_reg) {
    var n = sw_reg.showNotification(title, options);
  }).catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  });
}
```

Comment: oh Hi thanks for the reply. would you please provide the contact email id so i have more queries to be asked

Comment: Hi @zarina-veeru,
You can contact our support at [https://help.moengage.com/hc/en-us/requests/new](https://help.moengage.com/hc/en-us/requests/new)